# Load div content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I want to have something that loads a .jsp page into one div i have in index.jsp.

Currently i am using:

index.jsp: this function when i use the text property of the myWorkContent div place different random numbers every three seconds into the div.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
     function() {
         setInterval(function() {
             //var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
             $('#myWorkContent').load('dailyImages.jsp');
            // $('#myWorkContent').text(
            //         'I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> '
            //                 + randomnumber);
         }, 3000);
     });
</script>
```

Then i tried to make it load dailyImages.jsp into that div like i did for the random number. The dailyImages.jsp is as follows:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.Date;" %>

<font face="verdana" size="2">
Current Time :<%= new java.util.Date() %>
</font>
<img src="images/IMG_20131216_084621.jpg" style="height: 80px;" />
```

This div is loaded dynamically the first time, although the next times the date never changes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like your browser is caching the GET request. Either change the URL slightly each time you request the page (e.g. dummy parameter with a random number or counter) or change the server settings for that page so that the page is not cached (e.g. expired immediately). When in doubt use Fiddler2 to see what was returned and if it was cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you add something like below it will not load it from cache. It should work if it is a cache issue. You can give it a try.

```
$('#myWorkContent').load('dailyImages.jsp?' + (new Date()).getTime());
```

Comment: Can also be rewritten to

    $.ajax({
        url: 'dailyImages.jsp',
        cache: false
    }).done(function (content) {
        $('#myWorkContent').append(content);
    });

Comment: and how can i get that date in the dailyImages.jsp page?

Comment: This date is not sent for your jsp. You have to get the date in JSP like you are doing in your example. This date is added just to make sure browser can not cache the GET url, as we are adding time in the url each time its a new URL to browser so not cache.